# Django - get objects that have a related objects with certain field only

Tags: python, django, sqlite, foreign-keys

Django 1.11, Python 2.7

Given the following models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()
    ...

class Job(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Person,
        related_name='jobs'
    )
    workplace = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Workplace,
        related_name='workers'
    )
    position = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, choices=(
        (POSITION_1, POSITION_1),
        (POSITION_2, POSITION_2),
        (POSITION_3, POSITION_3),
    ))
```

A person can have several jobs with the same position and with different positions too.

```py
person1: [workplace1, POSITION_1], [workplace1, POSITION_2],
         [workplace2, POSITION_1]

person2: [workplace1, POSITION_2],
         [workplace2, POSITION_2]

person3: [workplace3, POSITION_3]
```

I want to write a single method in `PersonManager` which will retrieve all persons with multiple jobs of a certain given position (and that position only); or if multiple positions are given then persons that work in all of these positions.

- `Person.objects.get_multiple_jobs(jobs=[])` will return `person1, person2`
- `Person.objects.get_multiple_jobs(jobs=[POSITION_2])` will return `person2` ONLY (as he's the only one with only `POSITION_2` multiple jobs).
- `Person.objects.get_multiple_jobs(jobs=[POSITION_1, POSITION_2])` will return `person1`
- `Person.objects.get_multiple_jobs(jobs=[POSITION_3])` won't return anything

**Edit 1**: To clarify, I want the persons, with multiple jobs, that have jobs in **ALL** listed positions and **ONLY** them.

Using `Person.objects.annotate(position_count=Count('jobs')).filter(position_count__gt=1, jobs__position__in=[...])` won't work as in the 3rd case I'll get `person2` as well.

Chaining `filter`/`exclude` like `Person.objects.filter(jobs__position=POSITION_1).exclude(jobs__position__in=[POSITION_1,POSITION_3]` will work but it's not maintainable - what if in the future more positions will be added? Deciding which jobs to exclude dynamically is cumbersome. It also results in filters being very hard-codded when I wanted to encapsulate the logic under a single method of `PersonManager`.

I was thinking about using `Q` in the filtering or a sub-query but I can't come with a working query which is modular enough to work on all cases and enable maintainability too.

### Edit 2:

The solution, per [Dušan Maďar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4183498/du%C5%A1an-ma%C4%8Far) answer, after adjusting it to django 1.11:

I tried to change the syntax first and replace the inside `filter` of the `Count` with a simple `Case When`:

```py
 annotations['cnt_{}'.format(pos)] = Count(
                    Case(
                        When(
                            jobs__position=pos,
                            then=1
                        ),
                        default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField()
                    )
                )
```

But that didn't work.

The resulting query was:

```sql
SELECT "person"."id",
       "person"."name",
        ...
        COUNT(CASE WHEN "job"."position" = \'Driver\' TEHN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "cnt_Driver"
FROM "person" LEFT OUTER JOIN **long and irrelevant**
```

After playing with the SQL itself I found the sub-query I needed to make it work, as `COUNT` wouldn't do:

```sql
(SELECT COUNT(*) from "job" WHERE "job"."position" = 'Driver' and "job"."person_id" = "person"."id" ) as "cnt_Driver"
```

To reach this sub-query via django:

```py
sub =  Job.objects.filter(
             person=OuterRef('pk'),
             position=pos
       ).values('person').annotate(c=Count('*')).values_list('c')
```

The `.values('person')` is important - django adds its own `GROUP BY` clause which includes all the values of the schema (and thus only one result per person since all the `Jobs` are distinctly grouped), and with this step the `GROUP BY` will consist only from `"person"."id"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I was able to make it work according to your rules. Please note it's a `class method` on `Person` model, not a manager method.

```
class Person(models.Model):
   ...

    @classmethod
    def get_multiple_jobs(cls, positions=None):
        if positions is None:
            positions = []

        annotations = {}
        filters = []
        if positions:
            operator_ = "gt" if len(positions) == 1 else "gte"
            for position in positions:
                annotations[f"cnt_{position}"] = Count(
                    "jobs__position", filter=Q(jobs__position=position)
                )
                filters.append(Q(**{f"cnt_{position}__{operator_}": 1}))
            annotations["cnt_positions"] = Count("jobs__position", distinct=True)
            filters.append(Q(cnt_positions=len(positions)))
        else:
            annotations["cnt_positions"] = Count("jobs__position")
            filters.append(Q(cnt_positions__gt=1))

        return Person.objects.annotate(**annotations).filter(*filters).distinct()
```

You can call it as `Person.get_multiple_jobs()`.

Comment: I have, I just didn't include that part in my question (will edit it in). Your answer still doesn't suffice as the `__in=[..]` acts as an `OR` condition and will give me all persons, with multiple jobs, of EITHER ONE of the listed positions (they may also hold in more unlisted positions). I want the persons, with multiple jobs, that have jobs in ALL and ONLY listed positions.

Comment: So for a single position e.g `Driver` the resulting query would be `Person.objects.annotate(cnt_Driver=Count("jobs__position" ,filter=Q(jobs__position="Driver")).filter(cnt_Driver__gt=1)`. If I am correct this will give me all the persons that have at least one job as a driver - even if they have other jobs. I need it to give me all the persons that have at least on job as a driver and no other job. This will also have a similar problem for 2 or more positions if a person has a third (different) position (I will still get him).

Comment: @user3765713 updated - added a filter to ensure the number of distinct jobs a person has is the same as the position requested. I hope we're getting closer :). So `Person.get_multiple_jobs(positions=[POSITION_1])` returns an empty queryset.

Comment: Yes! Now it does what I wanted! I thought about the for-loop to create an annotations and filters per position, but I couldn't think of a good way to make the search exact. And your last edit helped it come together. It was simpler than I thought. Thanks! I had to adjust your solution to work with django 1.11 as well as replace the `Count(filter=...)` with a `Subquery` since the resulting SQL didn't do what it was supposed to do. I will edit my solution based on your answer to the question post